# Take in a file and shuffle all the middle letters in between

Tags: python, file, shuffle

I need to take a file and shuffle the middles letters of each word but I can't shuffle the first and last letters, and I only shuffle words longer then 3 characters. I think I can figure out a way to shuffle them if I can put each word into their own separate list where all the letters are separated. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So what have you tried to do? Where exactly are you having problems? Break it down, try to code it - as it stands there's no real question to answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
text = "Take in a file and shuffle all the middle letters in between"

words = text.split()

def shuffle(word):
    # get your word as a list
    word = list(word)

    # perform the shuffle operation

    # return the list as a string
    word = ''.join(word)

    return word

for word in words:
    if len(word) > 3:
        print word[0] + ' ' + shuffle(word[1:-1]) + ' ' + word[-1]
    else:
        print word
```

The shuffle algorithm is intentionally not implemented.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; it doesn't actually shuffle anything around, but it does create spaces in the word itself.

Comment: @Makoto , from the question : "I think I can figure out a way to shuffle them if I can put each word into their own separate list where all the letters are separated." 

I did not want to solve the complete problem. :-)

Comment: Fair enough (and totally justifiable).  Edit something in your reply so I can undo that downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Look at random.shuffle. It shuffles a list object in place which seems to be what youre aiming for. You can do something like this for shuffling the letters around

`

```
def scramble(word):

    output = list(word[1:-1])
    random.shuffle(output)
    output.append(word[-1])
    return word[0] + "".join(output)`
```

Just remember to import random

Comment: Thanks. Random.shuffle was quite useful =)

Answer (score 0):

```
#with open("words.txt",'w') as f:
#    f.write("one two three four five\nsix seven eight nine")

def get_words(f):
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word

import random
def shuffle_word(word):
    if len(word)>3:
        word=list(word)
        middle=word[1:-1]
        random.shuffle(middle)
        word[1:-1]=middle
        word="".join(word)
    return word

with open("words.txt") as f:
    #print list(get_words(f))
    #['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
    #print map(shuffle_word,get_words(f))
    #['one', 'two', 'trhee', 'four', 'fvie', 'six', 'sveen', 'eihgt', 'nnie']
    import tempfile
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp:
        tmp.write(" ".join(map(shuffle_word,get_words(f))))
        fname=tmp.name

import shutil
shutil.move(fname,"words.txt")
```

Comment: I assumed you didn't want to preserve newline characters. If you did, then simply yield them in get_words()